# Turn off keyboard shortcut

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, keyboard

Every once in a while when editing a formula, I want to add a parenthesis at the beginning of the line by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> to get `(`. However, I will accidentally press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> instead, which stands for `*`, and the whole line gets converted to some weird rich text with a small solid red square at the beginning of the line.

I don't know what that is for, but I never want to do it and I want to disable whatever is going on; it effectively means I have to delete the line and start again because I don't know how to undo it. In fact it's happened for a long time and I've only just figured out what was actually happening. I tried looking at keyboard shortcuts online but didn't find anything for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>. Note that this only happens at the beginning of the line.

How can I disable this keyboard shortcut?

Comment: I assume that Shift + 8 produces "*"; in that case, it [starts a bulleted list](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/MakeBulletedLists.html#desktop-tab). Does Undo (CTRL + Z) help? If not, search "keyboard shortcut" in this site for some pointers.

Comment: What you get is a Shift+Ctrl+8 input window as a local Box eg for Matrix in traditional form.  Depends on the keyboad, language for windows and Mathematica.  See $$C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\KeyEventTranslations.tr$$  for the key events with an $8$ and change its Modifier

Comment: I see this question has a few close votes, but I disagree. This is a functionality of Mathematica that's that's poorly documented, making this a useful question for other people. The question phrasing could do with a bit of clarification though.

Comment: It might be nice to see a more generalized version of this question that could manage for any given erroneous key press (I’m looking at you, F1) or accidental shortcut/mapping activation which one wants to avoid. Some features may be built in & could be addressed through menus, others like this question may not be.

Comment: I am also unsure why the question is attracting close votes, particularly under the "needs consultant or Wolfram support" and "needs clarity" categories. I find the question very clear and reproducible, and the desired outcome just as clear. There are also plenty of questions on keyboard shortcuts / non-menu command entry on this site, so it appears on topic to me. I voted not to close it, and would recommend that it be kept open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surprisingly, this behavior is not actually a keyboard shortcut as such. It's a style property for Input cells. To disable it, go to the menu `Format -> Edit Stylesheet...` and then open the `Default.nb` stylesheet that the current stylesheet is inheriting from. Then, use Ctrl + F (or whatever shortcut your OS uses for that) to search for to style definition of Input cells. Select the cell and press Ctrl + Shift + E (or use `Cell -> Show Expression` from the menu) to convert the cell to box from. You'll see the line  `"*" -> "Item"` under `StyleKeyMapping`. If you delete that (or just delete the entire `StyleKeyMapping` rule), Input cells should no longer get converted to Item cells when you start with them with a `*`.

Also note that you can actually define your own shortcuts for different cell types with this mechanism.

[image]

## Edit

If you can't edit the default stylesheet, you can [create a new one](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html) that overrides the default Input style and link that stylesheet to your notebook. I'm looking for an easier solution, so I might update this answer later.

Comment: Apologies, this answer is very detailed but I am still stumbling at the final step; I get exactly to what is displayed on your image but I can't seem to actually edit anything (i.e. I can't delete/edit that portion of the text). There is a message above that says "Make modifications to any definition using commands in the Format menu" but I don't see any commands there that seem relevant for editing/deleting text.

Comment: Modifying Default.nb is generally considered a "bad idea".  The preferred method would be to create a custom stylesheet and override the Input style.

Comment: you can try `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],  StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input"],    StyleKeyMapping -> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]`

Comment: or `StyleKeyMapping ->{}` to remove all to remove all short-cuts associated with `Input` cells.

Comment: @ihojnicki Not sure I would agree. Default.nb inherits form Core.nb. I'd say that Default.nb would be the place for a user to tinker with their own preferences while Core.nb would be the "hands off" territory. That said: making your own stylesheet is definitely the safe way to do it.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, it is included in the layout and the layout should not be modified.  On Windows and Linux, that tends to require Administrator permissions.

Comment: Thank you @kglr (and the OP) for your help. This has solved a problem which has been a (very minor but persistent) needle in my side for several years of Mathematica use.

Answer (score 7):

Some extra tips to anyone in my position (including future me):

I was unable to make any edits to Default.nb  (or any style file at all) using Mathematica's own "Edit Stylesheet" functions. I could edit (a copy of) the file directly using vi, but then Mathematica gave a rude beep whenever I used that file saying it had been edited outside Mathematica (sigh).

However, I was able to:

1. Create a new style file "NoItems.nb"
2. Edit the style file from the mathematica prompt, using kgir's suggestion in the comments:

   ```
   SetOptions[
     EvaluationNotebook[],  
     StyleDefinitions -> 
       Notebook[
         {
           Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
           Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
           StyleKeyMapping -> {"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort"}]
         },
         StyleDefinitions -> "NoItems.nb"
       ]
   ]
   ```
3. Make that the default style using the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61337720/mathematica-how-to-set-default-stylesheet) by typing:

   ```
   SetOptions[$FrontEnd, DefaultStyleDefinitions -> "NoItems.nb"]
   ```